# Change URL on ChannelFactory?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using channelfactory when connecting my client to the service using WCF like this :

```
new ChannelFactory<T>(endpointConfigurationName);
```

This will load all settings from the config file that is alot in this case. Now I need to change the URL before using the channel, how could this be done? I do not find any URL on the ChannelFactory? I could provide a EndpointAddress while creating the channel but I suspect that this will reset my settings from the configfile?

Im using channelfactory to avoid generating a new proxy for every change and to be able to set credentials.

Edit :

This is how I did solved it

```
    for(int i = 0; i < clientSection.Endpoints.Count; i++)
    {
        if(clientSection.Endpoints[i].Name == endpointConfigurationName)
        {
            var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(clientSection.Endpoints[i].Address.ToString());
            var netHttpBinding = new NetHttpBinding(clientSection.Endpoints[i].BindingConfiguration);
            var serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), netHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceEndpoint);

            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generic wrapper method:

```
public TProxy CreateChannel(string newEndpointAddress)
{
        _endpointAddress = newEndpointAddress;

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<TProxy>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(newEndpointAddress));

        return factory.CreateChannel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this will not read anything from the config file? I need it to use the settings of binding, behavior and so on from the config.

Comment: Well, you can use a configSection provider (having the ApplicationConfiguration) to read settings of endpoints, or use <appSettings> in App.config. Then you can use the method provided above.

Comment: How do you live without ApplicationSettings? )))

Answer (score 0):

Just were in same situation. Use multiple binding config. See:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DcServiceBasicBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:801/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DcServiceBasicBinding"
        contract="Service.IService" name="basicHttpDcServer"/>
      <endpoint address="http://10.0.0.1:801/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DcServiceBasicBinding"
        contract="Service.IService" name="VpnEndpoint"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And then, from your code, call ctor like this:

```
public void Init(string endpoint = Config.SERVICE_ENDPOINT) {
    _service = new ServiceClient(endpoint);
}
```

Where endpoint is endpoint name from configuration

P.S. removed some names for personal purposes.